# Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, backend

hi there i am new in mongoDB Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000 this I am getting in email when I am clicking on link which I got in email I am getting this image [image]

but here I am not able to find out what exactly collection calling or what exactly query was triggered?

please help me out
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems it because you are subscribed to the Google Groups "mongodb-user" group.

For other MongoDB technical support options, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/support/